# IntegrityError at /entry/21/add_comment NOT NULL constraint failed: auctions_comment.text

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, cs50

I am trying to create an e-commerce website where there is a problem occurring in the comment section where we need to add Comments

I created a model which calls Listing to get the listing id so that each listing have their own comment section

**models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    
    listing_id = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    uname = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="None")
    text = models.TextField()
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.uname} {self.cmt} {self.datetime}"
```

**views.py**

```
def add_comment(request,id):

    if request.user.username:
        list = Listing.objects.get(id=id)
        newItem = Comment()
        newItem.listing_id = list
        newItem.uname = request.user
        newItem.text=request.POST.get('comment')
        newItem.save()
        return redirect('add_comment', id=id)
    else:
        return redirect('index')
```

**urls.py**

```
path("entry/<int:id>/add_comment",views.add_comment,name="add_comment")
```

Comment: But if we go back and refresh the page then the comment is available

Comment: Please share with us more information. When do you see this error?  What do you exactly want to do?

Comment: Please post your `Listing` model and html template for more clarification

Comment: I think this field(`text`) is `NULL` value in your POST. Please print `request.POST.get('comment')` before `newItem.text=request.POST.get('comment')` . Another problem your in your html, You add `method='POST'` in `form` tag.